# The transitive reference don't works in gradle when use implementation project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a Core project where it has dependencies to other library.

```
Core build.gradle
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2'
        annotationProcessor  'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'
    }
```

And I have other  User project that reference to Core.
When the User project, does reference to Core library:

```
User build.gradle
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.example: core: 1.0'
    }
```

In User project I can acces at butterknife classes but when I reference at Core project

```
User build.gradle
    dependecies{
        implementation project(":core")
    }
```

I can't access to butterknife classes (Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.)

Is there any way to reference core and be able to use the dependencies referenced by core?

Comment: Where is the "compiler output for more details"?

Comment: This is the message: "error: cannot find symbol class BindView"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way [`implementation` configuration works](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation).

> The plugin exposes two [configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_dependency_configurations.html#managing_dependency_configurations) that can be used to declare dependencies: `api` and `implementation`. The `api` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API, whereas the `implementation` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.
>
> Dependencies appearing in the `api` configurations will be transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will appear on the compile classpath of consumers. **Dependencies found in the `implementation` configuration will, on the other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into the consumers' compile classpath.**

Either declare Butter Knife as an `api` dependency, or depend on it explicitly in `user/build.gradle`.